# Searching tables in a database for rows with same primary key

Tags: python, database, pandas, sqlite

I have a database `my_database.db` with thousands of tables consisting of time series of thousands of time points for about ten variables. An example is given in the code below with only five tables corresponding to names of cities, but in my actual problem, I have thousands. I need to select the row in each table corresponding to the timestamp `date_str` (the primary key for each table) if that timestamp exists in that table and, in the end, return a table that contains these rows along with the name of the table that the row came from.

Is there a way to speed up this code that doesn't involve restructuring the whole database (perhaps a way to call `SELECT` on all the tables at once instead of looping through the tables)? Note that `cities` is fixed while `date_str` is a parameter.

```
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd

conn = sqlite3.connect(f'my_database.db')
c = conn.cursor()

cities = ('sanfrancisco', 'dallas', 'newyork', 'chicago', 'miami')
columns = ('timestamp', 'population', 'averageincome')

def get_data(date_str):
    data = []
    for city in cities:
        c.execute(f"SELECT * from {city} WHERE timestamp='{date_str}'")
        result = c.fetchall()

        if result:  # will be False if no data was recorded for date given by date_str
            data.append([city] + list(result[0]))

    return pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
```

Comment: How is the performance right now? Have you done any benchmarking/profiling? Why are you doing `result[0]`, what else is in there? How are you calling the `get_data()` function, how is it used?

Comment: *five tables corresponding to names of cities* that's a pretty big indication that you should only be using one table, with the city as a column.

Comment: @AMC, I apologize but I haven't done any proper profiling yet. It just seemed like there would be a way to do this without a loop, so I figured I would ask. I may profile but given @Shawn's comment, I think I may need to restructure my database first. To answer your questions. `result[0]` is a tuple containing the columns associated with the given city and timestamp and `get_data()` is called repeatedly within a loop for different values of `timestamp`.

Comment: @Shawn, thank you for your suggestion. I will restructure my database and get back to you.

Comment: @VivekSubramanian Have you considered to use an index?

Comment: @Shawn, thank you again. Restructuring the database into a single table helped a lot. Now, I just query one table using the appropriate `where` clause to identify the city name and timestamp.